# are these two linear approximation same

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

Are these two concepts equivalent? If yes, how? Could anyone tell me?

We have $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}\\ \vdots\\ \vdots\\ x_{n1}\end{bmatrix},\;\cdots\cdots, x_m=\begin{bmatrix}x_{1m}\\ \vdots\\ \vdots\\ x_{nm}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now we form a matrix $X_1$ with $m-1$ column, i.e. from $x_1$ to $x_{m-1}$, and create another matrix $X_2$  with $x_2$ column to $x_m$ column. Suppose we assume that the data is generated from a linear dynamical system. In that case, $$\boxed{X_2=AX_1}$$ where $A$ is the linear operator, i.e. another matrix which needs to be computed by some numerical algorithm is not the point of this question, though.

Now the next concept is if we assume the data is from a linear dynamical system, then we can assume $$\boxed{x_2=Ax_1, x_3=Ax_2, x_4=Ax_3,\cdots ,x_m=Ax_{m-1}.}$$

Now my question is, mathematically, are they equivalent? Could anyone tell me how to convince a mixed audience? Thank you very much.

As @AlpUzman asked, what does ''they'' mean? I meant the above two different linearization methods to approximate $A$.

Comment: This looks very similar to Krylov spaces, the concept behind GMRES and CG, as you iterate powers of A onto the vector. There, we usually write something like $AQ_m = Q_{m+1}\cdot H$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal base.

Comment: @Laray, what you have written probably only you understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Marso Are the dimensions of $x_i$ variable? It seems $x_1$ is an $n$-tuple whereas $x_m$ is an $m$-tuple. Also it might be good to be more clear as to what "they" refers to.

Comment: @AlpUzman Thank you for your note. I have corrected them.

Comment: A "linear dynamical system" need not be a single matrix in this case, that is, the fact that the dynamics are linear does not imply that the dynamics are of the form $X_2  = A X_1$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. The equivalence of the condition "$x_2=Ax_1$, $x_3=Ax_2$, $x_4=Ax_3$,$\cdots$,$x_m=Ax_{m-1}$" and the condition "$X_2=AX_1$"   can be seen as a straightforward application of the definition of matrix multiplication on matrices $A$ and $X_1$ of compatible dimensions.

You can mention equivalence as a simple fact to the audience that has learned the introduction to linear algebra well.

To an audience unfamiliar with the introduction to linear algebra, you may want to demonstrate the equivalence step by step, writing out the definition of matrix multiplication.

To a mixed audience, well, it is always up to you what to do. If I suspect a significant of them may doubt the equivalence, I may use the following notations to convey it.

$$X_1=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3&\cdots& x_{m-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$
$$A\,X_1=\begin{bmatrix}Ax_1&Ax_2&Ax_3&\cdots& Ax_{m-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_2&x_3&x_4&\cdots& x_{m}\end{bmatrix}=X_2.$$

You and your audience may appreciate why $x_i$'s are written as column vectors.

---

Here is a relevant fact on matrix multiplication. Suppose $C=\begin{bmatrix}c_1&c_2&c_3&\cdots& c_{m}\end{bmatrix}$ is a $n\times m$ matrix, where $c_i$'s are column vectors of length $n$. Suppose $A$ is a $k\times n$ matrix.
Then the $k\times m$ matrix $AC=\begin{bmatrix}Ac_1&Ac_2&Ac_3&\cdots& Ac_{m}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Row vectors are not bad. We just have to put the operator matrix on the right side (pun intended). Suppose $R=\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\ r_2\\\vdots\\ r_m\end{bmatrix}$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, where $c_i$'s are row vectors of length $n$. Suppose $A$ is a $n\times k$ matrix.
Then the $m\times k$ matrix $$RA=\begin{bmatrix}r_1A\\ r_2A\\\vdots\\ r_mA\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your time and quick answer.

Comment: @miosaki You are welcome. Thanks for improving my answer.